# How to track a simple button click event in shopify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I want to add some javascript like:

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
   makeHttpPost();
});
```

that makes an http request whenever a button with id `foo` is clicked and i don't see a simple way to add this Javascript.

I saw that you could add an asset file and then reference it in a previous answer but i don't see anywhere to add an "asset". I only see a "files" section under settings.

I'd appreciate a step by step description of what to do and where to find what to do from the admin panel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add a new asset, you first click on the "Themes" link in the admin sidebar, and then "Template Editor".

You can then upload an asset by clicking "Add a new asset" under the asset folder. (See image below)

[image: Add a new asset]

To include the JavaScript file in the HTML, open `theme.liquid` from the template editor and add the following code in your `<head>` section (Changing the file name as required).

> {{ 'javascriptFileName.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}